# GridView item fades to become invisible when scrolling down

Tags: android, android-studio, gridview, android-adapter, baseadapter

The GridView item becomes invisible when I scroll it down. This does not happen all the time but generally happens on the MOTOROLA NEXUS SIX.

I haven't used VIEW.GONE or VIEW.INVISIBLE in my adapter code.

Can you please help me on this?

Below is the adapter code -

```
public LikeMindedUserAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<LMUserModel> listData) {
    mContext = context;
    mUtility = new Utility(mContext);
    mListData = listData;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (mListData != null && mListData.size() > 0)
        return mListData.size();
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_likeminded_user, null);
        viewHolder.tv_username = (CustomTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_username);
        viewHolder.tv_uinit = (CustomTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_uinit);
        viewHolder.iv_profile = (RoundedImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_profile);
        viewHolder.pbar = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pbar);
        viewHolder.iv_userpin = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_userpin);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    LMUserModel likeMindedUserModel = mListData.get(position);
    viewHolder.tv_username.setText(likeMindedUserModel.getName());
    viewHolder.tv_uinit.setText(likeMindedUserModel.getName());

    double userMatchingScore = 0;
    if (likeMindedUserModel.getCueModel() != null) {
        userMatchingScore = likeMindedUserModel.getCueModel().getMatchingScore();
    }

    String userGrade = likeMindedUserModel.getGrade();
    if (userGrade != null && !userGrade.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        mUtility.setUserProfilePicWithGrade(userGrade, userMatchingScore, viewHolder.iv_profile, viewHolder.iv_userpin);
    } else {
        userGrade = Constants.UserGrade.JUNIOR;
        mUtility.setUserProfilePicWithGrade(userGrade, userMatchingScore, viewHolder.iv_profile, viewHolder.iv_userpin);
    }
    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    private RoundedImageView iv_profile = null;
    private CustomTextView tv_username = null;
    private CustomTextView tv_uinit = null;
    private ProgressBar pbar = null;
    private ImageView iv_userpin = null;
}
```